# What's the deal with the CiviCRM election? Am I eligible to vote/run?

Tags: community

There's a CiviCRM election I heard about.  What's the deal? How do I vote or run for a position?

Answer (score 3):

The current election (October 2018) is to determine the structure of a board to oversee the CiviCRM project.  It will determine what the permanent board's mandate is as well as its structure.

You can [register to vote](https://civicrm.org/voter-registration-for-the-community-advisory-committee-process) until October 18th and/or [stand for election](https://civicrm.org/nomination-form-for-the-establishment-committee-of-the-community-advisory-committee) until October 15th. [This blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/josh/call-for-establishment-committee-nominations) has details.

Comment: Please note the blog post says: Nominations will be accepted through the end of day (UTC) October 10, 2018

Comment: KarinG, looks like the gitlab page now says Oct 15th. https://lab.civicrm.org/community/governance-summit-dev-camp/wikis/governance-summit/Governance-summit-decisions#election-of-the-establishment-committee

Comment: Blog still says Oct10 - not sure how one would unblog or retract emails.